# Unity get facebook friend's name, score, and picture on leaderboard

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, leaderboard, facebook-unity-sdk

The FriendSmash sample is kind of hard to follow and i was wondering if anybody had just a simple way to retrieve these using the Unity Facebook SDK?

Im pretty sure i have to use the QueryScores and ScoresCallback methods.
Not sure how though.

Basically i need a way to iterate through the list of friends and retrieve each of their names, scores, and profile pictures.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The graph explorer is a great way to explore and see how you can fetch names, scores and profiles:
`https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/`

The commands you put in there would be the same ones that goes into `FB.API()`.  The JSON response should also be the same.

Comment: Im not having trouble with the HTML GET. I need help getting the data out. I dont know how to iterate through the list of objects and obtain specific information per a friend and store it in each label.

Comment: The data you get back is a JSON string.  You just need a JSON deserializer to turn it into a dictionary or object and iterate over that.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
i completely missed this method!

private int getScoreFromEntry(object obj)
    {
        Dictionary<string,object> entry = (Dictionary<string,object>) obj;
        return Convert.ToInt32(entry["score"]);
    }